# Unable to send more buffered streams of data from node.js to the client

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm using GM, a GraphicsMagick for Node.js package to convert images to pdf on the server, and send them to Angular.js passing a buffered stream like so:

```
var comm = gm().command('convert')
for (page in pages) {
    comm.in('./docs/' + data.nomefile + '[' + pages[page] + ']')
}
comm.density(150, 150).compress('jpeg').stream('pdf', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (!err) {
                var bufs = [];
                stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    bufs.push(chunk)
                });
                stdout.on('end', function() {
                    var buf = Buffer.concat(bufs).toString('base64');
                    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
                    res.header('content-type', 'application/pdf');
                    res.send(buf)
                })
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to send to the client more than few pdf pages (depending on their size).

On Angular I decode these images using this service:

```
$http.get(baseUrl+imageUrl, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).
            success(function(data) {
              var pdfData=Base64Service.ConvertArrayBuffer(data);
              cbk(pdfData);
            }).

            error(function(data, status) {
              var err= 'Request failed with status: ' + status;
              cbk(err);
            });
```

On the controller:

```
window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfData);
```

When the limit is exceeded I get only a blank page and nothing else.

Comment: Suggestion: you should be able to simply set headers and then `stdout.pipe(res);` on the server side to avoid buffering. Question: why not simply open a new window on the client that navigates to the remote endpoint instead? That way you won't run into data uri length issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  [mscdex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050455/mscdex) suggestion, this is how I managed to properly render all the images:

Server side:

```
var comm = gm().command('convert')
for (page in pages) {
comm.in('./docs/' + data.nomefile + '[' + pages[page] + ']')
}
comm.density(150, 150).compress('jpeg').stream('pdf', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (!err) {
            res.header('content-type', 'application/pdf');
            stdout.pipe(res)
        }
```

Client Angular.js service:

```
createPdf: function(imageId, pagesArray) { 
$http({
      method: 'GET',
      cache: false,
      url: baseUrl + 'image/createPdf/',
      params: {
          id: imageId,
          pages: JSON.stringify(pagesArray)
      },
      responseType: "arraybuffer"
  }).success(function(pdfData) {
      var file = new Blob([pdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      window.open(fileURL);
  });
}
```